# What is the difference between the following two declarations and when should they be used

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript. I am confused between the following two notations where the newly created objects inherit the properties. How are they different and when should i use them?

Code 1:

```
 var Vehicle = function Vehicle() {
       this.wheel=2
    }

    var vehicle = new Vehicle();
    alert(vehicle.wheel);
```

Code 2:

```
 var Vehicle = function Vehicle() {
    }
    Vehicle.prototype.wheel = 4;
    var vehicle = new Vehicle();
    alert(vehicle.wheel);
```

When is the keyword `prototype` used?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties defined on prototype will be shared by all the instances. So if you create 10 vehicles, they just share the wheel property(only one), and each vehicle **doesn't** have a wheel property **on itself**.

Answer (score 2):

The most important difference is that when you add a property to the prototype of a function and instantiate a new object from it, that property is accessed in the new object by stepping up the inheritance chain rather than it being directly on the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about prototype, there were lots of threads in stackoverflow, do a little search.
For example read this [article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/prototypes-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/). Or grab a book which is the best approach to learn something, I recommend this great book, JavaScript: [The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do)

In general it's much better using prototype in terms of memory consumption and prototype chain that can be extendable.